# Java SQL - How to use a field attribute as a variable

Tags: java, sql, sql-update, derby

I have an ACCOUNTINFO table and I am trying to use the "Balance" field attribute as a variable to compare it with another variable, "amount". By doing this I will be able to subtract the amount from the balance and then show the remain balance, however, I cannot get this to work, can anyone give me a hand?

My code is below:

```
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        String Balance = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        if (rs.next()){
            Balance = rs.getString(1);
        }
        if (amount < Long.valueOf(Balance).longValue()){
            ResultSet res = null;
            res = stm.executeQuery("UPDATE AccountInfo SET Balance = Balance -"+ amount);
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException sql) {

        System.out.println(sql);
    }

    return flag; 
}
    try {
        String Balance = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        if (rs.next()){
            Balance = rs.getString(1);
        }
        if (amount < Long.valueOf(Balance).longValue()){
            ResultSet res = null;
            res = stm.executeQuery("UPDATE AccountInfo SET Balance = Balance -"+ amount);
        }
```

Comment: I see a NullPointerException at  `if (rs.next()) {` (line 6) am I wrong? At that position rs could only be null

Comment: @mauros Sorry Mauros what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that  if you set `rs` to null and in the next line you call `rs.next()` at runtime you should have a NullPointerException since `rs` is null. And since you're catching only SQLException there you may not catch that exception and not log it. But I'm not a JVM so I may be wrong.

Comment: Take a look at this page [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) here you can see this 'ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);' and this is what you are not doing, you're not executing a query to get the Balance.

Comment: Did it work? Another thing I think you should change is `res = stm.executeQuery("UPDATE AccountInfo SET Balance = Balance -"+ amount);` I think this is not going to work since executeQuery method is only for query. Use `res = stm.executeUpdate("UPDATE AccountInfo SET Balance = Balance -"+ amount);` instead [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))

Comment: I was getting a NullPointerException but I didn't know how to fix it. i Have tried changing it to res = stm.executeUpdate but I get an error message when trying to compile saying "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.sql.ResultSet"

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  String Balance = null;
  ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT balance FROM ACCOUNTINFO WHERE ...CONDITIONS...");
  if (rs.next()){
    Balance = rs.getString(1);
  }
  if (amount < Long.valueOf(Balance).longValue()){
    ResultSet res = null;
    res = stm.executeUpdate("UPDATE AccountInfo SET Balance = Balance -" + amount);
  }
}
catch (SQLException sql) {
  System.out.println(sql);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
}
```

You have to add the CONDITIONS to the select query.